# Powershell ALL AD Users and their Group Memberships

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

Looking to write a powershell script that will pull ALL AD users, their group memberships and the groups Description Field.

I have been using two scripts to accomplish this, and just manually manipulating them in excel. Any attempt to combine them has been met with error.

```
 Import-module activedirectory
$ou ="DC=blah,DC=blah"
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $OU  | select -expandproperty name | % {
$group= "$_"
$result += Get-ADGroupMember -identity "$_" | select @{n="Group";e={$group}},name
}



$result | export-csv 'c:\users\membership.csv' -notypeinformation
```

And:

```
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Groups = ForEach ($G in (Get-ADGroup -Filter * ))
{

$UN = Get-ADGroup $G -Properties Description | select name, description


New-Object PSObject -Property @{
Desc=$UN.description
Name=$UN.name
}

}

$Groups | Export-CSV C:\users\GroupDesc.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: You might want to check out `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I am unsure what that would accomplish here. He is pulling the groups from an AD query. Not from the users side where something like domain users would be lost without the addition of `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`.

Comment: How do you expect to handle nested arrays? If a person is in 5 groups, do you want their name to appear 5 times, once for each group? Do you intend to get nested group info (i.e. User A is a member of Group1. Group1 is a member of Group2. Should Group2 show up for User A?)

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Looking to get the user each time per group.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i've got this right, this will pull all users from AD and get the groups each one is a member of (including the groups description). After everything is done it puts the info into a csv.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$OU = "DC=blah,DC=blah"

#$allUsers = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" # all users that are enabled
#$allUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * # all users
$allUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU
$results = @()

foreach($user in $allUsers)
{

    $userGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user
    foreach($group in $userGroups)
    {
        $adGroup = Get-ADGroup -Identity $group -Properties Description
        $results += $adGroup | Select-Object -Property @{name='User';expression={$user.sAMAccountName}},Name,Description
    }
}
$results | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Membership.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Bluecakes, however I am receiving the following error "does not contain a method named op_Addition". I know this has to do with combining arrays however.

Comment: Note, error had to due to the $result = @(). Needed changed to $results. Still having issues however with it not including all groups.

Comment: When you say it's not including all groups, do you mean all the groups in the OU you're searching? Do you know which groups it's not including? `Get-ADUser` with a wildcard should pick up every group in the specified OU, if you want to find all groups remove the `-SearchBase $OU` part.

Comment: @MadBoy Thank you for the edits, i did not use an LDAP Filter initially because the syntax can be difficult for those new to PowerShell, I also think the LDAP Filter that was edited in does not fit with OP wanting "ALL AD users" (This would include disabled users which the filter ignores).

Comment: No problem. It makes sense now.